# In SQL, query a table by transposing column results

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldf

**Background**

Forgive the title of this question, as I'm not really sure how to describe what I'm trying to do.

I have a SQL table, `d`, that looks like this:

```
+--+---+------------+------------+
|id|sex|event_type_1|event_type_2|
+--+---+------------+------------+
|a |m  |1           |1           |
|b |f  |0           |1           |
|c |f  |1           |0           |
|d |m  |0           |1           |
+--+---+------------+------------+
```

**The Problem**

I'm trying to write a query that yields the following summary of counts of `event_type_1` and `event_type_2` cut (grouped?) by `sex`:

```
+-------------+-----+-----+
|             |  m  |  f  |
+-------------+-----+-----+
|event_type_1 |  1  |  1  |
+-------------+-----+-----+
|event_type_2 |  2  |  1  |
+-------------+-----+-----+
```

The thing is, this seems to involve some kind of transposition of the 2 `event_type` columns into rows of the query result that I'm not familiar with as a novice SQL user.

**What I've tried**

I've so far come up with the following query:

```
SELECT event_type_1, event_type_2, count(sex)
FROM d
group by event_type_1, event_type_2
```

But that only gives me this:

```
+------------+------------+-----+
|event_type_1|event_type_2|count|
+------------+------------+-----+
|1           |1           |1    |
|1           |0           |1    |
|0           |1           |2    |
+------------+------------+-----+
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I'm using the `sqldf` package in `R` to connect to a PostgreSQL db on my local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `lateral join` to unpivot the data.  Then use conditional aggregate to calculate `m` and `f`:

```
select v.which,
       count(*) filter (where d.sex = 'm') as m,
       count(*) filter (where d.sex = 'f') as f
from d cross join lateral
     (values (d.event_type_1, 'event_type_1'),
             (d.event_type_2, 'event_type_2')
     ) v(val, which)
where v.val = 1
group by v.which;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1e88f2dc28878eb65bdb4dc606b93b42) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I'm getting some errors as I run this -- `relation "t" does not exist`. What is `t` ? And `v`, for that matter?

Comment: @logjammin: `t` is the name of the underlying table! :) Substitute your real name. (And `v` is the name of the derived table.)

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter, but when I change `t` to `d`, my table's real name, I get another set of errors: `operator does not exist: text = integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: @logjammin . . . I see in the question that you named your table `d`.  That was a typo.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- whatever edits you just made were just what was needed. It runs perfectly now. I think I can fiddle with it from here to make `event_type_1` be the first row instead of the second. Thanks so much, sir!

Comment: @logjammin: The reason for the type mismatch is probably that the real (undisclosed) data type of `event_type_1` and `event_type_2` is `text`, while Gordon (understandably) assumes `ìnteger`. Change to `where v.val = '1'` and it should work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- If I wanted to run this in SQLite instead of Postgres, what would I need to change? I changed the db<>fiddle to SQLite and it shows an error `near "as": syntax error`. No worries if this is out-of-scope for this question; don't want to over-burden.

Comment: @logjammin . . . The answer would be quite different for SQLite.  I would suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks!